# Assigning an array with std::fgetc() return

Tags: c++, string, c++11, wav, riff

I am trying to store the first `4` `char`s of a `.awv` file using the `std::fgetc` function

This is what I have

```
FILE* WAVF = fopen(FName, "rb");
std::vector<std::string> ID;
ID[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    ID[i] = fgetc(WAVF);
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF696431309 in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000010.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)!

Your vector `ID` is empty. By calling `operator[]` on an empty `std::vector`, invoking an [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Access_out_of_bounds). You got lucky that your program got crashed, saying "Access violation".

You need instead:

```
// create a vector of string and initialize 4 empty strings
std::vector<std::string> ID(4); 

for (auto& element: ID)
{
    element = some `std::string`s
}
```

---

However, in your case, [`std::fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc) returns `int`ger as

> The obtained character on success or `EOF` on failure.

So you might want the data structures such as `std::vector<char>` or (at best) `std::string`.